# Updated to 11.10 and now flash is gone. How to completely wipe it?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, apt, flash, cleanup

There was some problem while upgrading my ubuntu to the last version at roughly 90%. Apparently all the system is fine but there was a problem with flash. Now it's reported as not installed, but I simply can't install it again using apt-get or a package from adobe's site.

Is there a way to completely remove any reference to flash on my system so that I can re-install it properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-nonfree flashplugin-installer gnash gnash-common mozilla-plugin-gnash swfdec-mozilla

sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so

sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so

sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper*flash*so

rm -f ~/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*so
```